# TakeWhile fails for unapparent reason

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

In my following Linq query, that I run against a SQL Server 2012 instance, I attempt to read the most recent records up to the previously established `MasterId` marker (which is a `Guid`).

```
var cdc = crm.CdcContacts
             .Include("CdcMaster")
             .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn)
             .TakeWhile(x => x.MasterId != marker)
             .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedOn);
```

However, this fails.

> "Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet\r\n
>   .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn)\r\n    .TakeWhile(x => x.Id !=
>   new Guid(\"ABFF5734-F59F-EA11-80CB-005056BC5333\"))' by
>   'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate
>   either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed
>   information."

The link in the error message leads to the page on Client vs. Server evaluation so I'm pretty sure the `TakeWhile` can't be evaluated - I know the cursor logic doesn't work in the same way in older versions of SQL Server, perhaps this could be an explanation.

When I replace the `TakeWhile` with a simple `Take(10)`, everything works - this evaluates neatly as `SELECT TOP 10 *` but I get no output of the generated SQL through the console logger factory before the exception hits.

Can someone help me understand what possible reasons might exist for this `TakeWhile` to not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exception indicates unsupported LINQ method.

I wish EF Core provided documentation with list of supported / unsupported LINQ methods (and CLR properties/methods) like EF6, but up to now they didn't, so it's trial and error.

But `TakeWhile` and `SkipWhile` definitely are one of unsupported (and I'm guess they'll never be). I'm not sure why `Queryable` contains them at all - probably for compatibility with `Enumerable` methods. But AFAIK no query provider (except LINQ to Object of course) does implement them, since they have no natural translation to SQL.

You can of course switch to `Enumerable` methods (with `AsEnumerable()` as explained in the link), but that's not good in general. You'd better express your query with other standard LINQ operators.

---

P.S. The database and EF Core database provider doesn't matter - the aforementioned methods are not supported by EF Core LINQ query processor.